# How to update Intel (Broadwell) HD graphics on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, mesa

I am currently on Ubuntu 16.04.1, and from what I read, Mesa 12 was supposed to introduce ([source](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=mesa-12-released&num=1)) OpenGL 4.x on Intel Boradwell, but doing `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` results in `OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 12.0.6`

My processor is the i5 5200U, with Intel HD 5500 graphics.

Is there anything I should do to enable OpenGL 4.x? What can I do?

Comment: OpenGL is not the same thing as OpenGL ES. [The latest version of OpenGL ES is 3.2.](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/) What does `glxinfo | fgrep 'OpenGL core profile version string'` return?

Comment: 4.3!!! Thank you! Didn't know that. In a related topic, do you know when will 16.04.2 arrive? Also, please reply so I can mark your reply as correct :)

Comment: 16.04.2 has arrived: http://distrowatch.com/?newsid=09726.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL is not the same thing as OpenGL ES. [The latest version of OpenGL ES is 3.2.](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/)

To get the version of OpenGL, run:

```
glxinfo | fgrep 'OpenGL core profile version string'
```